# Why numpy zero initialized array giving number other than zeros?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, voxel, xtensor

I am trying to re implement numpy code in C++ xtensor library for my master thesis. But I could not able to understand why numpy zero initialized array gives number(10,20,43,28,....). See the code below.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
    
scene_size = np.array([4, 40, 48], dtype=np.float32)
voxel_size = np.array([0.4, 0.2, 0.2], dtype=np.float32)
grid_size = np.array([10, 200, 240], dtype=np.int64)
lidar_coord = np.array([0, 20, 3], dtype=np.float32)
max_point_number = 45
#lidar point clouds, each point has 4 fields (x,y,z,intensity)
np.random.shuffle(point_cloud)  #(N,4) N number of points
    
    
shifted_coord = point_cloud[:, :3] + lidar_coord
# reverse the point cloud coordinate (X, Y, Z) -> (Z, Y, X)
voxel_index = np.floor(
    shifted_coord[:, ::-1] / voxel_size).astype(np.int)  #(N, 3)
    
bound_x = np.logical_and(
    voxel_index[:, 2] >= 0, voxel_index[:, 2] < grid_size[2]) #(N, )
    
bound_y = np.logical_and(
    voxel_index[:, 1] >= 0, voxel_index[:, 1] < grid_size[1]) #(N, )
    
bound_z = np.logical_and(
    voxel_index[:, 0] >= 0, voxel_index[:, 0] < grid_size[0]) #(N,)
    
    
bound_box = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(bound_x, bound_y), bound_z) #(N, )
    
    
point_cloud = point_cloud[bound_box] ##(dynmaic_value, 4)
voxel_index = voxel_index[bound_box] ##(dynmaic_value, 3)
    
# [K, 3] coordinate buffer as described in the paper
coordinate_buffer = np.unique(voxel_index, axis=0)  #removing the duplicates in axis 0
#which means for an example voxel_index[10] = (1,2,3) and voxel_index[20] = (1,2,3), remove one of them
K = len(coordinate_buffer)
T = max_point_number
#Not storing any points, but zeros initialized array of shape K
# [K, 1] store number of points in each voxel grid
number_buffer = np.zeros(shape=(K), dtype=np.int64)
    
# [K, T, 7] feature buffer as described in the paper
feature_buffer = np.zeros(shape=(K, T, 7), dtype=np.float32)
    
# build a reverse index for coordinate buffer
index_buffer = {}
for i in range(K):
    index_buffer[tuple(coordinate_buffer[i])] = i
    
for voxel, point in zip(voxel_index, point_cloud):
    index = index_buffer[tuple(voxel)]
    number = number_buffer[index]
    print(number)  #according to my understand it should be zero, but giving number like 4,19,34,23,26
    #Because number buffer is zeros initialized 
    if number < T:
        feature_buffer[index, number, :4] = point
        number_buffer[index] += 1
```

You can see in the comment section of above code,

1. I did not understand, how come number_buffer gives real values other than 0 and greater than zero?

I am using third party library to achieve numpy functionalities in C++.

Could anyone explain me how the code is behaving?

How come zero initialized array gives real values greater than 0(which means number of points stored in each voxel)?

Code implemented in C++ using xtensor works properly until the condition:

```
if(number <T):
```

In C++, number will be zero always, since number_buffer is zero initialized both in numpy and C++. So C++ code gives 0, but numpy code gives other than zeros for certain indexs(like values greater than zeros, which means number of point stored in each voxel).

I am happy to provide more info I needed. Please help me out with the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of the code? Please provide a [mcve]; it's not helpful for us to have to go through all that code and work out the part that we think you think is unexpected

Comment: Is the C++ code even relevant to a problem where you're just trying to initialise a numpy array with zero values, for example? Or is it just a distraction (since it has no bearing on how Python will behave)

Comment: @roganjosh, I think, I can remove C++ code for better understanding by the readers.